# Dear E/editor and R/reviewers? The correct form of capitalization

Tags: capitalization

I am writing a "response to reviewers' letter" for answering the reviewer's comments on my paper.
I want to know which one is correct to start my letter:

**Dear Editor and reviewers;**

**Dear Editor and Reviewers;**

**Dear editor and reviewers;**

(I have googled and found some records that wrote: "Dear Editor-in-chief", "Dear Editor-in-Chief", "Dear editor", and "Dear Editor".

But still I don't know which letters should be capital in "dear editor and reviewers", and why?

Comment: Safest to use capitals for both. Make the recipients feel good.  “Dear Jack and Jill ...”. I doubt if anyone would care much: their attention is far more on your reply.

Comment: I have to agree with the above: capitalize. "Dear Editor" is definitely correct, because you're addressing the holder of a specific position; some sources recommend capitalizing "Dear Colleagues" and the like, although it's less clear-cut. But "Dear Editor and reviewers" would definitely look odd.

Comment: @Anton: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Staurt F: Thank you for the explanation.